# Ember CLI unusable after installing addon

Tags: ember-cli

I stupidly tried to install [`ember-cli-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-rename) using `ember install ember-cli-rename`. I got a successful message:

```
Yarn: Installed ember-cli-rename
Installed addon package.
```

But now ember is unusable. Any command I give it returns

```
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-rename/lib/commands/rename.js:5:25)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-rename/lib/tasks/generate-file-list.js:8:21)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-rename/lib/tasks/process-move-files.js:8:21)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-mv/lib/commands/move.js:5:22)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-mv/lib/tasks/verify-file.js:8:29)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-mv/lib/tasks/move-file.js:8:21)
DEPRECATION: `ember-cli/ext/promise` is deprecated, use `rsvp` instead. Required here: 
  Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/my-project/frontend/my-project/node_modules/ember-cli-mv/lib/tasks/update-paths.js:8:20)
Cannot find module 'ember-cli/lib/utilities/string'


Stack Trace and Error Report: 

/var/folders/pm/4g51l697zhtl2vj7/T/error.dump.da9acb8bm3zgrpw9sd3.log
```

How can I undo this problem?

Comment: I noticed that `package.json` and `yarn.lock` had been modified, so I reverted them to their previous state in git, and so far that seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can also just remove the line

`"ember-cli-rename": "0.0.4",`

from your package.json then run yarn again. That worked for me.